# how to rotate .eps file

Tags: rotating, eps

I have a problem with rotation of `.eps` files for my dissertation. Initially, I thought it was a problem during conversion of `.pdf` to `.eps`. I tried the conversion in several ways: using Adobe Acrobat 9 Pro in Windows, in Linux the following commands: `inkscape input.pdf --export-eps=output.eps`  and `pdftops -eps file.pdf`. All methods give good .eps files, but when I try to rotate (90 degree rotation) them in Latex, nothing works.
I used `\includegraphics[width=6.0 in,angle=90]`, also `\special{ps: gsave -90 rotate}\......\special{ps: grestore }`, and some other methods but with no luck.
Any solutions (Windows, Linux, Mac) will be appreciated.

Comment: try `rotate = 90` in `\includegraphics` I can't remember if that is it but it is worth a try.

Comment: `angle` is the option @dustin is thinking of --- it's interesting that it has no effect, seemingly

Comment: Also, why in the world would you convert from PDF to EPS? You can include PDFs as images.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make sure you have loaded the `graphicx` package not `graphics` then

```
\includegraphics[width=6.0in,angle=90]{file}
```

should work.

Note if it is an EPS file then you need latex (and it may not show rotated in a dvi previewer) if you are using pdflatex you should convert the EPS to pdf first (or if I read your question correctly, just use the original pdf not the EPS).

Comment: It does not rotate the caption. Better to use rotating package. But rotating has conflict with tablefootnote.

Comment: @chandresh the question did not ask to rotate the caption.

Comment: I agree but sometimes that is inherent in the question.

Comment: It cover the caption text  after rotated eps using xelatex and graphicx.

Answer (score 5):

[From the Latex Wikibooks page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Rotations):

The package rotating gives you the possibility to rotate any object of an arbitrary angle. Once you have loaded it with the standard command in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{rotating}
```

you can use three new environments:

```
\begin{sideways}
%...
\end{sideways}
```

it will rotate the whole argument by 90 degrees counterclockwise. Moreover:

```
\begin{turn}{30}
%...
\end{turn}
```

it will turn the argument of 30 degrees. You can give any angle as an argument, whether it is positive or negative. It will leave the necessary space to avoid any overlapping of text.

```
\begin{rotate}{30}
%...
\end{rotate}
```

like turn, but it will not add any extra space.

Also, note the warning:

> Many DVI viewers do not support rotating of text and tables. The text will be displayed normally. You must convert your DVI file to a PDF document and view it in a PDF viewer to see the rotation in effect. Take care however that printing from those PDF files may rotate the respective page again in the same direction under certain circumstances. This behaviour can be influenced by the settings of your dvi2pdf converter, look at your manual for further information.

Comment: `rotating` is really only for the sidewaystable environment the old `turn` and `rotate` are mainly for compatibility with the old latex2.09 version of the package, they are implemented as simple wrappers around the standard `\rotatebox` although neither is needed for graphicx which has built in rotation support.